# How to change default home page in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am new to opencart. I just want two main pages, one will be listing all the products(by default in opencart) and the other will describes about the company. So how can i change the default home page.

These two pages should have different headers. How can i set the route for this kind of pages.

Ya i tried as follows

created new file under common as `default.tpl`

In my `home.tpl` I used

```
<?php if(!isset($this->request->get['route'])){
    echo $header;
}else{
    echo $default;
}
?>
```

But it is not rendering default. I also created a controller under `controller/common/default.php` with following lines

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonDefault extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/default.tpl';
        $this->render();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It would be easier to write a seperate header file... if you open `catalog/controller/common/home.php` 
you will find the following code

```
    $this->children = array(
        'common/column_left',
        'common/column_right',
        'common/content_top',
        'common/content_bottom',
        'common/footer',
        'common/header'
    );
```

you could change this to

```
    $this->children = array(
        'common/column_left',
        'common/column_right',
        'common/content_top',
        'common/content_bottom',
        'common/footer',
        'common/headerhome'
    );
```

and then open:

```
catalog/view/theme/default/common/home.tpl
```

and find the following line:

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
```

and change it to:

```
<?php echo $headerhome; ?>
```

and then copy:

`catalog/controller/common/header.php`

and rename it

`headerhome.php`

and then open

`catalog/controller/common/headerhome.php`

and find the following line

```
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
```

and change to:

```
class ControllerCommonHeaderhome extends Controller {
```

then find:

```
$this->language->load('common/header');
```

and change to:

```
$this->language->load('common/header');
```

then find the following code:

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl')) {
    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl';
} else {
    $this->template = 'default/template/common/header.tpl';
}
```

and change it to:

```
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/headerhome.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/headerhome.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/common/headerhome.tpl';
    }
```

and then copy

```
catalog/view/theme/default/common/header.tpl
```

and rename to:

```
catalog/view/theme/default/common/headerhome.tpl
```

then copy:

```
catalog/language/english/common/header.php
```

and rename to:

```
catalog/language/english/common/headerhome.php
```

you can then edit the following file to reflect the style changes that you want:

`catalog/view/theme/default/common/headerhome.tpl`

you can then edit the following file to reflect the language changes that you want:

`catalog/language/english/common/headerhome.php`

This means that the home page will show headerhome and all other pages will show the standard header, which if you are only going to have two pages like you said earlier this solves your problem...

Comment: Who down voted this... This answer sets out everything you asked for in your question... please click the tick if it answered it... there are a lot of haters on this site...

Answer (score 0):

`$this->request->get['route']`

You will get the current page path using this piece of code. Write a condition based on that in your common/header.php controller file and use separate template files.

Comment: It is not showing anything. if i `echo $this->request->get['route']` this in home.tpl

Comment: Did you echo it in other pages ?

Comment: In other page it is coming but in home page how can i identify it. My home page url is `localhost://opencart`

Comment: So 
`if(!isset($this->request->get['route'])){
 /* condition for home page*/ 
}else{
 /* condition for other pages*/ 
}`

You can do like this.

Comment: Please read my answer again. "You will get the current page path using this piece of code. Write a condition based on that in your common/header.php controller file and use separate template files."