# how to change homepage in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

how to change homepage as a loginpage in opencart.

I need to change the homepage as login page, users first loaded the page as login page then login action completed after the view a products.

Please help me solve and how to do?

Comment: change index page link to login page link

Comment: where to change? Location please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764880/how-to-change-default-home-page-in-opencart check this hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you don't actually want to change the homepage, but rather force customers to first log in before browsing your site. In any case, this would be a more sensible thing to do and would leave your home page intact and viewable once customer is logged in.  Bear in mind, doing this will effectively prevent any search engine bots from properly indexing your site since a bot cannot "log in".

If you want to redirect non-logged in customers to the login page you can do it like this.  Edit **index.php** just before `//Router` and add this block of code:

```
// REDIRECT NON LOGGED IN CUSTOMERS

// Check that customer is not logged in and that they are not already on the login page
if (!$registry->get('customer')->isLogged() && (empty($request->get['route']) || $request->get['route'] != 'account/login')) {

    // Set a session variable to bring them back to current page after they log in
    $session->data['redirect'] = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    // Set http status code and redirect
    header('Status: ' . 302);
    header('Location: ' . $url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'), 1, 302);
    exit(); 
}
```